# Solrj Imports - package not found

Tags: java, api, netbeans, solr, solrj

I am trying to use SolrJ in Netbeans for my java application.

In the project library, I imported all the SolrJ java files :

```
    org.apache.solr.client.solrj
```

But in my code, when I add :

```
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj;
```

It doesn't work and it says: `package does not exist`.

I have tried several methods but the package is never found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think you can write the import that way. It should be more like this:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.*;
```

I don't know if Netbeans has an auto-import feature (have never used this IDE), but you might try to see if you can get Netbeans to auto-import something from `solrj`. Try `SolrServer` or `QueryResponse`.

Also, are you using Maven? Maven should make all this a little easier for you.

If that fails, I'm not sure what it could be, but here's a link to one or two people who had a problem very similar to yours: https://netbeans.org/projects/cnd/lists/users/archive/2007-12/message/86.